# how to define z-index valueof html5 shapes?

Tags: javascript, html

i have drawn html5 shapes rectangle, line ans curve using canvas.getContext('2d'). I am confusing that how can i give them z-index?

Answer (score 2):

In Html5 canvas drawing API, you cannot set the z-index of any shape drawn in canvas. Because canvas is instant drawing mode once you draw you cannot access that drawn shape because canvas in not part of DOM. But fakeing the z-index you can draw shapes in some order that first drawn shape will take the 0 index and so on.

You can use EaselJS  a javascript librabry which will provide you the  retained display mode and you can set the index of each child and access that child easily.

Comment: Thanks for response Alex and modhur. Actually i want to draw text inside rectangle (drawn by ctx.strokeRect(x,y,WIDTH,HEIGHT)).But text is floating outside the rectangle boundary drawn using ctx.fiiText(textValue,x,y) (i.e. text is not wrapping according to width and height of rectangle). so i am trying to insert textarea/div inside rectangle. so that on rezing rectangle text inside it get wrap(adjust) itself.